# 分類モデルの作成

Tags: python, 機械学習

分類モデルの作成をしてまして、モデルの選択
ロジスティック回帰と決定木、ランダムフォレスト、SVMの4つのモデルを作成して比較で　# for文でリストからモデルを取り出し、学習と予測、F1値の出力を行う。為のコードがどうしてもわからなく悩んでいます。ご教示お願い致します。

コード

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# JupyterNotebook上でグラフを表示する設定
%matplotlib inline
# DataFrameで全ての列を表示する設定
pd.options.display.max_columns = None

# 要約統計量を表示
dataset = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

dataset = dataset[['survived', 'pclass', 'sex', 'age', 'sibsp', 'parch', 'fare', 'embarked']]
dataset.head()

dataset.describe()

# 各列の欠損値の数を確認
a = dataset.isnull().sum()
b = pd.isnull(dataset[['survived', 'pclass', 'sex', 'age', 'sibsp', 'parch', 'fare', 'embarked']]).sum()

print(a)
print(b)

# ageの欠損値を平均値にて補完
dataset['age'] = dataset['age'].fillna(dataset['age'].mean())
dataset.head()


# 乗船者数の多い港を value_counts メソッドで確認
dataset_em = dataset['embarked'].value_counts()
print(dataset_em)

# 補完後の欠損値が0であることを確認  #embarkedに欠損値あり 2
dataset.info()

# datasetのsexとembarkedをダミー変数に変換してdataset2に代入する
dataset2 = pd.get_dummies(data=dataset, columns=['sex', 'embarked'])

# dataset2のデータの最初の5行を表示
dataset2.head()

# dataset2より目的変数と説明変数に該当する列を取得してnumpy配列に変換し、変数YとXに格納する
# Y:目的変数に該当する列
Y = np.array(dataset2['survived'])
# X:説明変数に該当する列。dataset2からsurvivedを除外
X = np.array(dataset2[['survived', 'pclass', 'age', 'sibsp', 'parch', 'fare', 'sex_female', 'sex_male', 'embarked_C', 'embarked_Q', 'embarked_S']])

# 形状を確認
print("Y=", Y.shape, ", X=", X.shape)

# X と Y を 機械学習用データとテストデータに7:3に分ける(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# 機械学習用データを、学習データと検証データに7:3に分ける(X_train, X_valid, Y_train, Y_valid)
X_train, X_valid, Y_train, Y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, Y_train, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# 形状を確認:X_train, X_valid, X_test, Y_train, Y_valid, Y_test
print("Y_train", Y_train.shape, ", X_train", X_train.shape)
print("Y_valid", Y_valid.shape, ", X_valid",X_valid.shape)
print("Y_test", Y_test.shape, ", X_test", X_test.shape)
```

**下記コードのモデルの選択でロジスティック回帰と決定木、ランダムフォレスト、SVMの4つのモデルを作成して比較**

```
# 必要なライブラリのインポート
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

# 空のリストを用意
model_list = []

# リストにモデルを追加。それぞれの引数は警告を出さないための設定
model_list.append(LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='multinomial', max_iter=1000))
model_list.append(DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy'))
model_list.append(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100))
model_list.append(SVC(gamma='scale'))

# for文でリストからモデルを取り出し、学習と予測、F1値の出力を行う　←これが分かりません。
```

Answer (score 0):

「# リストにモデルを追加。それぞれの引数は警告を出さないための設定」という行と、
「# for文でリストからモデルを取り出し、学習と予測、F1値の出力を行う」という行の間で、４つのモデルを、配列model_listに追加(append)していますから、配列の中身は以下のようになっているはずです。

```
model_list[0]に、LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='multinomial', max_iter=1000)
model_list[1]に、DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
model_list[2]に、RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
model_list[3]に、SVC(gamma='scale')
```

あとは、

```
f_value_list = [] #F1値を記録する配列を用意する

for i in range(4): #4つのモデルで学習と予測を行い、それぞれのF1値を得る。得られたF1値は配列f_value_listに記録する。
    model = model_list[i] # i番目のモデルを取り出す。
    # modelを用いた学習と予測を行ってF値を得る。(モデルの仕様などが判らないので、学習と予測をするコード、F値を計算するコード等を示すことができません。省略させて頂きます）
    # F1値が変数FVに入ると仮定する
    f_value_list[i] = FV

for i in range(4): # F1値を表示する
    print('{0} 番目のモデルのF値: {1}'.format{i+1, f_value_list[i]})
```

というような感じで進めていけば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 詳細なコメントありがとうございます。上記のコードを追記して、実装した所、
下記のエラーが発生してしまいました。
追加で、""の前にｆを追加しましたが、同じエラーが起きてしまい、実装されませんでした。大変申し訳ございませんが、ご教示お願いいたします。

  File "<ipython-input-36-022d381ef971>", line 19
    print(f"{0}番目のモデルのF値:{1}".format{i+1, f_value_list[i]})
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: print('{0} 番目のモデルのF値: {1}'.format{i+1, f_value_list[i]}) は、
print('{0} 番目のモデルのF値: {1}'.format(i+1, f_value_list[i])ですね。

私の回答は、こういう感じでコーディングを進めていけばという参考として書いたもので、完全に動作するものではありません。

コメントに書いたように、モデルの仕様などが判らないので、学習と予測をするコード、F値を計算するコード等を示すことができません。
このサイトはコーディングをタダで請け負うお人好しが集まっている場所ではありませんこと、ご承知ください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。不快に思わせてしまい、大変申し訳ございません。今後気を付けます。